# Draw an image at a specified position with ImageResizer in .NET

Tags: .net, imageresizer

I've been creating images at a specific position on a canvas for a while now with few issues. For instance, if I have a canvas that's 200px X 250px, I can draw an image that's 25px X 15px with its top position at 40 and its left position at 60. Recently, I came across a new image manipulating API called ImageResizer. It seems that it's faster/better than the System.Drawing/GDI+ APIs I've been using, and I'm thinking of switching to it to gain a performance boost. But it doesn't seem like I can accomplish the same goal with this API.

Is there a way to draw an image at a specific position using the ImageResizer managed API for .NET? If so, can someone point me in the right direction? Nothing in the documentation shows that it's possible and my internet searches have come up blank.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something, that while achievable, goes slightly against the grain of ImageResizer API design. ImageResizer is not a graphics API, but rather for end-to-end image processing. For a more flexible API, take a look at the upcoming [Imageflow](https://imageflow.io) project.

ImageResizer's Watermark plugin is capable of overlaying and compositing images, but it's one of the less well designed parts of the API, having been modeled after the WinForms layout/docking model.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and thanks for the heads up on the new project. (It looks interesting.) I'll play around with the Watermark plugin to see how it goes.